# How do I add a line legend to a list plot?

Tags: graphics, legending, filling

I want to label a `ListPlot` using `LineLegend` with the line colours corresponding to the filling. For example if I use this function to create two sparse arrays:

```
array[length_Integer, values_Integer] := 
 SparseArray[
  RandomSample[Range[length], values] -> 
   RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {values}], length]
```

When I plot them, I want to label them by filling using a line, not a point. `LineLegend` doesn't seem to work (`LegendMarkers` has no effect):

```
ListPlot[{array[50, 12], array[50, 15]}, PlotStyle -> Black, 
 PlotRange -> All, 
 Filling -> {{1 -> {Axis, Red}}, {2 -> {Axis, Blue}}}, 
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{Red, Blue}, {"1", "2"}, LegendMarkers -> Automatic]]
```

[image]

Is this expected behaviour or am I missing something really obvious here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A workaround is to add `HoldForm`:

```
ListPlot[{array[50, 12], array[50, 15]}, PlotStyle -> Black, PlotRange -> All, 
 Filling -> {{1 -> {Axis, Red}}, {2 -> {Axis, Blue}}}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  HoldForm @ LineLegend[{Red, Blue}, {"1", "2"}, LegendMarkers -> Automatic]]
```

[image]

Comment: AHA! Perfect - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a no frills example of a legend that almost does what you want:

```
legend = ImageCrop@Graphics[{
     Text[Style["1-----", Blue], {0, 1/20}],
     Text[Style["2-----", Red], {0, -1/20}]
     }];
ListPlot[{array[50, 12], array[50, 15]},
 PlotStyle -> Black, PlotRange -> All,
 Filling -> {{1 -> {Axis, Red}}, {2 -> {Axis, Blue}}},
 PlotLegends -> legend]
```

It should be easy to draw a thick line over the dashed text, but I haven't been able to add that bit of finesse.