# How to remove lines through the legend markers in ListPlot?

Tags: plotting, legending, marker

I am drawing a plot with some legends. It seems the legend markers will always have lines through them since I have to use `Joined->True` for this plot. The legend markers also seem to be always larger than those in the plot. My question is, is it possible to get rid of those lines through the legend markers and also make the legend markers smaller? Besides, is there a way to remove the grey outlines around the legend markers?

[image]

The code I used for this plot is

```
ListPlot[{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, (1/2) {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}, Joined -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Dashed, AbsoluteThickness[1]}, {Red, Dashed, 
    AbsoluteThickness[1]}}, 
 PlotMarkers -> {{Graphics@{Disk[]}, 0.04}, {Graphics@{Rectangle[]}, 
    0.04}}, InterpolationOrder -> 1, 
 Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[PointLegend[
    Automatic, {Style["Series 1", FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 
      FontSize -> 9, ScriptMinSize -> 6], 
     Style["Series 2", FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", FontSize -> 9,
       ScriptMinSize -> 6]}], {0.3, 0.8}], ImageSize -> 240]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just add the options `Joined -> False` and  `BaseStyle -> EdgeForm[]` to `PointLegend` in your code to get

[image]

If you don't like the red syntax highlighting of `BaseStyle -> EdgeForm[]` you can use `Method -> { BaseStyle -> EdgeForm[]}`.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a work around.

```
Show[ListPlot[{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, (1/2) {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, 
  PlotMarkers -> {{Graphics@{EdgeForm[None], Disk[]}, 
     0.04}, {Graphics@{EdgeForm[None], Rectangle[]}, 0.04}}, 
  Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   Placed[
    PointLegend[
     Automatic, {Style["Series 1", FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 
       FontSize -> 9, ScriptMinSize -> 6], 
      Style["Series 2", FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 
       FontSize -> 9, ScriptMinSize -> 6]}], {0.3, 0.8}], 
  ImageSize -> 240], 
 ListLinePlot[{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, (1/2) {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Dashed, AbsoluteThickness[1]}, {Red, Dashed, 
     AbsoluteThickness[1]}}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Define a standalone `legend`:

```
legend = PointLegend[{Blue, Red},
          {Style["Series 1", FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", FontSize -> 9, ScriptMinSize -> 6], 
           Style["Series 2", FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", FontSize -> 9, ScriptMinSize -> 6]}, 
          LegendMarkers -> {{Graphics@{EdgeForm[None], Disk[]}, 0.04}, 
                            {Graphics@{EdgeForm[None], Rectangle[]}, 0.04}}]
```

[image]

Unfortunately, simply adding `PlotLegends -> Placed[legend, {0.3, 0.8}]` doesn't work:

```
ListPlot[{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, (1/2) {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}, 
  Joined -> True, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Dashed, AbsoluteThickness[1]}, {Red, Dashed, 
     AbsoluteThickness[1]}}, 
  PlotMarkers -> {{Graphics@{Disk[]}, 0.04}, {Graphics@{Rectangle[]}, 
     0.04}}, InterpolationOrder -> 1, 
  Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[legend, {0.3, 0.8}],
  ImageSize -> 240]
```

[image]

However, [this approach](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/133569/22013) with `HoldForm` is succesful:

```
ListPlot[{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, (1/2) {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}, 
  Joined -> True, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Dashed, AbsoluteThickness[1]}, {Red, Dashed, 
     AbsoluteThickness[1]}}, 
  PlotMarkers -> {{Graphics@{Disk[]}, 0.04}, {Graphics@{Rectangle[]}, 
     0.04}}, InterpolationOrder -> 1, 
  Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[HoldForm@Evaluate@legend, {0.3, 0.8}], 
  ImageSize -> 240]
```

[image]

Alternatively, `Legended` is a workaround:

```
Legended[
  ListPlot[{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, (1/2) {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}, Joined -> True, 
   PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Dashed, AbsoluteThickness[1]}, {Red, Dashed, 
      AbsoluteThickness[1]}}, 
   PlotMarkers -> {{Graphics@{Disk[]}, 0.04}, {Graphics@{Rectangle[]},
       0.04}}, InterpolationOrder -> 1, 
   Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, ImageSize -> 240], 
  Placed[legend, {0.3, 0.8}]]
```

> same plot as above

Answer (score 2):

This is just an answer for your last question. You can get rid of the border of your markers in the legend by specifying `EdgeForm[None]`, e.g.:

```
ListPlot[
    {{1,2,3,4,5}, (1/2) {1,2,3,4,5}},
    Joined->True,
    PlotStyle->{
        {Blue,Dashed,AbsoluteThickness[1]},
        {Red,Dashed,AbsoluteThickness[1]}
    },
    PlotMarkers->{
        {Graphics@{EdgeForm[None],Disk[]},0.04},
        {Graphics@{EdgeForm[None],Rectangle[]},0.04}
    },
    InterpolationOrder->1,
    Frame->{{True,False},{True,False}},
    PlotLegends->Placed[
        PointLegend[
            Automatic,
            {
            Style["Series 1",FontFamily->"Times New Roman",FontSize->9,ScriptMinSize->6],
            Style["Series 2",FontFamily->"Times New Roman",FontSize->9,ScriptMinSize->6]
            }
        ],
        {0.3,0.8}
    ],
    ImageSize->240
]
```

[image]